# Проблема с перезагрузкой страницы на хостинге Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular2, firebase, angular-routing

Приложение на ангуляр загрузил на firebase. Есть несколько роутов, все работает нормально, однако если обновить страницу то выдает 404. На локальном сервере работало все нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

https://warm-evenings.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: серверный роутинг неправильно настроен

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы. Я даже нашел как можно его настроить, однако не имею понятия как это сделать для собранного ангуляр проекта.

Comment: всегда отдавать `index.html`